# Probability of a dice game with an emphasis on the number $4$

Tags: probability, dice

If I were to roll a set of $4\,$ *four-sided* dice $4\,$ times, what is the probability that on each of the $4\,$ dice rolls, the sum of the dice will be divisible by $4\,$?

Comment: I'd guess exactly 1/4, since if you consider the sum mod 4, each die in turn transforms the sum so far into a new sum uniformly.

Comment: @JMD The distribution of sums for multiple dice is not uniform. there is a $\frac{1}{6}$ chance that $2\,$ $6$-sided dice will result in a sum of $7$ despite the range being [2,12] would suggest a $\frac{1}{11}$ chance

Comment: The distribution of *sums* is nonuniform, but the distribution of sums mod 4 *is* uniform.

Comment: I agree with @MJD's comment, except that he's forgetting the fact that we have four trials, and we want to know the chance that they all succeed.  (But this is easy to take care of.)

Comment: @MJD is right (and this holds for any sided-ness).  So the answer here is just $p=(1/4)^4=1/256$.

Comment: Holy Crap! You are correct @MJD & I learned something new!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will be the $4$-th power of the probability that it happens when we toss the $4$ dice once.

Presumably we are to assume that the $4$ sides are numbered $1$ to $4$. Since we are working modulo $4$, we might as well assume it is $0$ to $3$.

We want to find the sum of the coefficients of terms in the expansion of $(1+x+x^2+x^3)^4$ that are of the shape $x^{4t}$. Let the expansion be 
$$f(x)=a_0+a_1 x+a_2x^2+\cdots +a_{12}x^{12}.$$
Substitute in turn $x=1,-i,i,-i$. We get
$$f(1)=a_0+a_1+a_2+a_3+\cdots+a_{12}=4^4.$$
$$f(-1)=a_0-a_1+a_2-a_3+\cdots +a_{12}=0.$$
$$f(i)=a_0+ia_1-a_2-ia_3+\cdots +a_{12}=0.$$
$$f(-i)=a_0-ia_1-a_2+ia_3+\cdots+a_{12}=0.$$
Add up. The only thing that survives is coefficients divisible by $4$, each multiplied by $4$. The sum of these coefficients is therefore $\frac{4^4}{4}$.

It follows that the probability that when we toss once the sum is divisible by $4$ is $\frac{\frac{4^4}{4}}{4^4}$. Thus the required probability is
$$\left(\frac{\frac{4^4}{4}}{4^4}\right)^4.$$
We could simplify, but then we would lose a lot of $4$'s.

Comment: That last line cracked me up!